# how to highlight invalid section — twitter bootstrap/jquery/validate plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I have a form in twitter bootstrap:

```
<div class="form-div">
<form id="fvujq-form1" method="post" action="">
                    <div class="control-group name">
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>Name *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name">
                    </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group email">
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>E-Mail *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email">
                    </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group comment">
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>Your comment *</label>
                        <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                    </div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> 
            </form>
        </div>
```

and this is how I validate it with bassistance Validate plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#fvujq-form1").validate({
            submitHandler:function(form) {
                SubmittingForm();
            },
            success: function(label) {
                 label.html("&#10004;").addClass("valid");
               },
            onfocusout: function(element) { $(element).valid(); },
            focusInvalid: false,
            highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                 $('.form-div').find('.control-group' + element.id).addClass('error');
              },
              unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                 $('.form-div').find('.control-group' + element.id).removeClass('error');
              },
            errorClass: "help-inline",
            errorElement: "strong"
```

I want to add .error to the div currently validated, but this code adds class to every .control-group occurence, not only validated one :(

thx 4 yr help.

Answer (score 5):

[JSFiddler Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/2890/)

This will validate as you leave each field or when you hit the submit button all fields that meet the rules will present errors.

HTML

```
<form action="" id="fvujq-form1" class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>  
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="name">Your Name</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="name" id="name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="email">Email Address</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="email" id="email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="comment">Comment</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="comment" id="comment">
      </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="form-actions">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#fvujq-form1').validate(
 {
  rules: {
    name: {
      minlength: 2,
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    comment: {
      minlength: 2,
      required: true
    },
  },
  highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
  },
  success: function(element) {
    element
    .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
    .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: This works great.  However, I have a help item next to each item:
      ...
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="name" id="name">
        <p class="help-inline">name description goes here</p>
      </div>
      ...
This causes the error message from jquery.validate to change the location of the help (pushes the help text down).  Also, it would be great if the error message would also be styled to the error class so that the colors are all consistently red.

Is there an easy way to do this?